# Folded Normal Distribution Shape Parameter?

Tags: normal-distribution, folded-normal-distribution

Scipy, a python library, says the pdf of a folded normal distribution is as shown here: [http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/tutorial/stats/continuous_foldnorm.html](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/%7Efrancois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/tutorial/stats/continuous_foldnorm.html)

Wikipedia says it's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution

I've tried messing around with the algebra, but the two PDF's do not appear equivalent to me for a shape parameter $c=\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$. Am I doing something wrong or misinterpreting something or are the two actually equivalent?